# Is there a correct way to pack PBR textures in a texture atlas without the need of replacing the models on the scene in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, game-development, blender, texture-atlas

I have a scene in Unity, a map, where all the models are placed correctly already. The problem is, that the memory is already overloaded, and many props have their own textures. I want to make a 4k atlases and pack 10-15 models' textures in each atlas respectively.

I was trying to use MA Atlas Packer, but the problem is, that it adjusts the UV map of each model, and create a separate version of each asset for use with texture atlas, obviously. Is there a more correct way of making atlases, when you already have a complete map, without the need of replacing the initial models with adjusted new ones?

Comment: The uvs of the models in question need to be adjusted in order to map the appropriate portion of the packed texture to the model.  UV is in the range of 0-1 for both axes, usually a models texture occupies the entire uv range.  Thus, if the texture now occupies the range of 0-0.2, the model needs the uv adjusted to the new range.  You don't technically need new models, but the uvs of those models do need adjustment.